# Resolved [project.chts.springboot.exception.UserNotFoundException: Invalid email or password !, Try again.]

Tags: spring-boot, maven, exception, try-catch

**Controller**

```
 @Controller
 public class UserListController {

        @PostMapping("/login")
        public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> signIn(@RequestBody UserList 
            userlist) throws UserNotFoundException{
            {
                 UserList user = 
                 userListService.findUserByEmailAndPassword(userlist);
                if (user == null)
                    
                    return new ResponseEntity<>("User not found!", 
                      HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
                
                return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
                    
            }
        
        }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class UserListService {

    // check mail and pass
    public UserList findUserByEmailAndPassword(UserList 
        userlist)throws UserNotFoundException {
        try {
            UserList user = 
            userListRepository.findByEmail(userlist.getEmail());
            String rawPassword = userlist.getPassword();
            if (user != null && 
                userlist.getEmail().equals(user.getEmail())
                    && passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, 
                      user.getPassword())) {
                UserList Result = user;
                return Result;
            }
            throw new UserNotFoundException("Invalid email or password !, Try again.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }   
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserListRepository extends JpaRepository<UserList, 
        Integer> {
       UserList findByEmail(String email);
}
```

**Confuguration File**

```
@Configuration
//to indicate there are one or more bean methods  for process by spring container
public class SecurityConfig {
     @Bean//it produces bean to get managed by spring container
     public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
          // PasswordEncoder service interface to encode passwords by BCryptPasswordEncoder
          PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
          return encoder;
     }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNOF1.png)}
Postman error

Comment: Give brief infromation about your problem. Please describe where you get error, which error you get.

Comment: The above error I got in spring-boot IDE when i send request from frontend, and in postman post request error please refer attached image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try use *Optionals* rather than user object directly.

```
UserList user;
Optionals userOptional = findByEmail(userlist.getEmail());
if(userOptional.isPresent())
{
user= userOptional.get();
if(passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, 
                      user.getPassword())          
{
 UserList Result = user;
  return Result;
} 
} 
else
{
throw new UserNotFoundException("Invalid email or password !, Try again.");
}
```